# bash: trouble with find and sed in a directory

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

Pulling my hair out - somebody save me from an early Q-ball.

I have a folder with loads of powerpoint files and I want to change a substring in each title. All of them are of the form "lecture 2 2014.pptx" and I want to change "2014" to "2016".

Insider the directory I try commands like:

`find . -name "*2014*" | xargs -0 sed -i 's/2014/2016/g'`

to no avail. Any advice?

**Edit** my goal is to change the file name. "Lecture 2 2014.pptx" to "Lecture 2 2016.pptx"

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27727005/3776858

Comment: Thanks Cyrus, can't say that helps.

Comment: @invictus but it is exactly what you asking for.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to know where I am erring with `find`+ `sed`. I know you can use `mv`. Thanks either way.

Comment: Moreover, `mv` just creates a new file with "2016", when I want to replace "2014" with "2016". That is, replace the existing files, not copy the existing files with new names.

Comment: Wait, so when you say "change the title" you mean "change the filename"? I'm confused...

Comment: Sorry, poor use of language on my part, indeed I want to change the file name.

Comment: Sed changes file contents, not file names. You really want `mv` (or one of the `rename`s).

Answer (score 0):

`rename s/2014/2016/ *2014.pptx`

If your list is too long to expand by shell try:

`find -name \*2014.pptx -exec rename s/2014/2016/ {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

`rename` was already mentioned. Be aware that there are two version floating around: one with the syntax

```
rename [options] expression replacement file...
```

and one with the syntax

```
rename s/old/new/ file...
```

As an alternative: a simple Bash loop with a regex extracting the "2014" from each file name, replacing it with "2016"

```
re='(.*)2014(.*)'

for fname in *2014*; do
    [[ $fname =~ $re ]]
    mv "$fname" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}2016${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done
```